# Fade in UIButton images after they load from URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I'm using AFNetworking method to load my images into UIBUttons. My goal is to show the image with a fade animation after it loads.

```
     [leftBtn setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:leftImageUrl]] placeholderImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^() {leftBtn.alpha = 1;}completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
            } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                //
            }];

Capturing 'leftBtn' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle
```

I understand why I get the above warning and looking for a smart way to solve it.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use something like:

```
__weak UIButton *weakLeftBtn = leftBtn;
[leftBtn setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL      
                                               URLWithString:leftImageUrl]] 
               placeholderImage:nil 
                       forState:UIControlStateNormal 
                        success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

                              [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^() {

                                   weakLeftBtn.alpha = 1;

                              }completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
               } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
           // if something went wront
}];
```

**UPDATE:** In your code `leftBtn` points to a block and the block points back to `leftBtn`. This causes a retain cycle. In my code `leftBtn` points to the block, but the block points to `weakLeftBtn`, which is declared with a `__weak` qualifier, meaning that it will point correctly to `leftBtn` as long as it's alive without keeping a strong relationship with it. So in this case `leftBtn` "owns" the block, but the block doesn't "own" any local or instance variables.

Some worthwhile reads on this topic:

- [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [Working with Blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html)
- [Practical Memory Management](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-1000810)

Comment: Thanks. So by doing so I just told the compiler that this UIButton is weak and he got nothing to worry about? Another question, When do I use __ besides in the above? Thanks

Comment: @Sha: I've just revised my answer.